# How can we generate Dynamic email field and username for postman

Tags: api, automation, environment-variables, postman, dynamic-variables

I need to generate a dynamic email address, username for API automation testing in postman. can you help me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options on how you can get what you need.

1. Using already defined dynamic variables, such as timestamp: For example where you need a new email address, just use this:

   ```
   user_{{$timestamp}}@example.com
   ```

   The request will be sent with something like: user_1497475549@example.com
2. Define an variable in the pre-request script:

   ```
   var randomEmail = 'DO YOUR PREFERRED RANDOMIZATION HERE';
   pm.setEnvironmentVariable("email", randomEmail);
   ```

   and use that variable like {{email}} when sending the request.

Comment: If I want to retrieve the email address used by the variable than how can I achieve this as response body doesn't give email address.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your last question.